# Adding properties to details pane in Windows 7 and Vista for my application file type

Tags: c#, .net, shell, windows-7, windows-vista

I have a file type for my application for which i want to show some custom information in Details Pane(which appears at the bottom) in windows explorer in vista and win 7. Like Microsoft Word file type (.docx) has properties on Details Pane in vista and window 7 that show author property and e.t.c i have some custom information for my file which i want to show. I want it to be a c# .net 2.0 application that does it for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at this link: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

Comment: And this q&a : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510002/how-to-use-windows-7-features-in-my-simple-net-application-without-any-new-api

Comment: with windows API Code pack one can enable win taskbar features than i am aware of, are you suggesting using the same code i can add properties in details pane? if yes can you give a hint, thanks

Comment: this is a tough one, couldnt find the answer anywhere yet

Comment: No, API code pack will not help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* a tough one. You need to implement a [property handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266532.aspx). A [property handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144131.aspx) is a COM object which knows how to extract properties from your files. I think it can use out-of-process activation so you may be able to use .NET 2.0, but be prepared for a lot of COM interop stuff. The [All-in-one code framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/55110) has some examples of shell extension objects written in C++ and in C# for .NET 4, which should at least give you pointers. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200245/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-a-managed-property-handler-shell-extension).

Comment: Also note that this should NOT be done in .NET 2 - you should use C++ or .NET 4.  Using .NET 2 can cause major instabilities if another shell addin exists using .NET 1.1, etc, since you can't (prior to CLR 4) load multiple CLR instances into a process.

Comment: Right, this is why I mentioned out-of-process activation.

Answer (score 2):

Information for what to display in each file type is in the registry under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\

You could create a sub key at install time for your file type (by extension), and set the properties you want displayed.